# Rspec testing rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake

I have a simple rake task with a `puts` in it

```
namespace :atask
  task something: :environment do
    puts 'Foo'
  end
end
```

My spec is as follows

```
describe 'atask:something' do
  before { MyApp.Application.load_tasks }

  context 'one' do
    it do
      Rake::Task['atask:something'].invoke
    end
  end

  context 'two' do
    it do
      Rake::Task['atask:something'].invoke
    end
  end

  context 'three' do
    it do
      Rake::Task['atask:something'].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see it has 3 contexts and 3 it blocks. So I should see 'Foo' in the console three times, once for each time the task is invoked. However, I only see 'Foo' once in the console even though it is invoked three times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that when a rake task has been `invoke`d it won't be ran again. You have to either `reenable` the task after invocation or use `execute`

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this. Fixing this issue cost me WAY TOO much time.